# ANDROID Sqlite no such table error -existing data base -

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-intent

My dataBase :

[image: database screenshot]

my dataBaseHelper :

```
package com.up.ridechaser;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.up.ridechaser/databases/";
    private static String DB_NAME = "DB.sqlite";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "lines";
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE "+ TABLE_NAME +" (`_id` INTEGER NOT NULL,`linename` VARCHAR,`fromgare`  VARCHAR,`togare`    VARCHAR,    PRIMARY KEY(_id)    )";
    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
    private final Context myContext;


    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.myContext = context;
    }

    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
        if (dbExist) {
        } else {
            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }

    }

    private boolean checkDataBase() {

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try {
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        } catch (SQLiteException e) {

            // database does't exist yet.

        }

        if (checkDB != null) {

            checkDB.close();

        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {

        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {

        if (myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();

        super.close();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        try {
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        }
        catch(SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS lines");
        onCreate(db);
    }

    private static final String[] COLUMNS = { "_id", "linename", "fromgare", "togare" };

    public line getLine(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query("lines", COLUMNS, " _id = ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null,
                null);

        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        line Line = new line();
        Line.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
        Line.setLinename(cursor.getString(1));
        Line.setFromgare(cursor.getString(2));
        Line.setTogare(cursor.getString(3));

        // log
        Log.d("getline(" + id + ")", Line.toString());

        return Line;
    }

}
```

my main_activity :

```
package com.up.ridechaser;

import java.io.IOException;
import com.up.ridechaser.DataBaseHelper;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);

        myDbHelper.getLine(1);

        try {
            myDbHelper.createDataBase();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            throw new Error("Unable to create database");
        }

        try {
            myDbHelper.openDataBase();
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            throw sqle;
        }


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

> 07-03 09:03:10.821: W/dalvikvm(679): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409bf1f8) 07-03 09:03:10.841: E/AndroidRuntime(679): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 07-03 09:03:10.841: E/AndroidRuntime(679): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.up.ridechaser/com.up.ridechaser.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: lines: , while compiling: SELECT id, linename, fromgare, togare FROM lines WHERE  id
>   = ? 07-03 09:03:10.841: E/AndroidRuntime(679):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956) 07-03 09:03:10.841: E/AndroidRuntime(679):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981) 07-03 09:03:10.841: E/AndroidRuntime(679):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123) 07-03 09:03:10.841: E/AndroidRuntime(679):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147) 07-03 09:03:10.841: E/AndroidRuntime(679):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 07-03 09:03:10.841: E/AndroidRuntime(679):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 07-03 09:03:10.841: E/AndroidRuntime(679):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424) 07-03 09:03:10.841: E/AndroidRuntime(679):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 07-03 09:03:10.841: E/AndroidRuntime(679):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 07-03 09:03:10.841: E/AndroidRuntime(679):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784) 07-03 09:03:10.841: E/AndroidRuntime(679):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551) 07-03 09:03:10.841: E/AndroidRuntime(679):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 07-03 09:03:10.841: E/AndroidRuntime(679): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: lines: , while compiling: SELECT id, linename, fromgare, togare FROM lines WHERE  id
>   = ? 07-03 09:03:10.841: E/AndroidRuntime(679):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method) 07-03 09:03:10.841: E/AndroidRuntime(679):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:68) 07-03 09:03:10.841: E/AndroidRuntime(679):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileSql(SQLiteProgram.java:143) 07-03 09:03:10.841: E/AndroidRuntime(679):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileAndbindAllArgs(SQLiteProgram.java:361) 07-03 09:03:10.841: E/AndroidRuntime(679):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:127) 07-03 09:03:10.841: E/AndroidRuntime(679):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:94) 07-03 09:03:10.841: E/AndroidRuntime(679):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.(SQLiteQuery.java:53) 07-03 09:03:10.841: E/AndroidRuntime(679):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:47) 07-03 09:03:10.841: E/AndroidRuntime(679):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1564) 07-03 09:03:10.841: E/AndroidRuntime(679):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1449) 07-03 09:03:10.841: E/AndroidRuntime(679):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1405) 07-03 09:03:10.841: E/AndroidRuntime(679):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1523) 07-03 09:03:10.841: E/AndroidRuntime(679):    at com.up.ridechaser.DataBaseHelper.getLine(DataBaseHelper.java:120) 07-03 09:03:10.841: E/AndroidRuntime(679):     at com.up.ridechaser.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21) 07-03 09:03:10.841: E/AndroidRuntime(679):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4466) 07-03 09:03:10.841: E/AndroidRuntime(679):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049) 07-03 09:03:10.841: E/AndroidRuntime(679):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)

plz help on that !

Answer (score 1):

i'ts happen to me all the time, you should delete your app and install it again. because the device remember the last version of your sqlLite database.
hope its help :)

Comment: the error still in my code and i can't found it , i try to use an existing sqlite data base , it's kinda hard , some help ?

Comment: Please look on this link - >http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109438/how-to-use-an-existing-database-with-an-android-application

Comment: My App is live on Playstore. Now what can I do?